# synchronize offline stored soup collections in sequential order

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

How to synchronize offline stored soup collections in sequential order instead of parallel execution and how to start the offline stored soup collection sync initiation post acknowledgment of another soup collection ?